# Trumpet vine is not growing after 4 months

Tags: fertilizer, raised-beds, vines, trellis

I purchased 4 Violet Trumpet Vine plants and planted them in a raised bed that I have built on the side of our garden shed.

The problem is that none of them have grown at all within 4 months (since September).

I used a wooden trellis and tied the vines to the trellis. The plants are bedded in general-purpose soil and I used cardboard as a weed barrier.

[image]

The first two weeks I (hand) watered them daily, then I switched over to watering them once a week, until the winter rains started setting in.

Based on their position, they get about 5 hours of direct sunlight and indirect sunlight for the rest of the day. I am located in Northern California (zone 9).

So far, I haven't tried fertilizer as the nursery hasn't recommended using any, as long as the soil is good quality.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Sounds normal to me - they're woody-ish plants, which tend to have the ":Sleep", "Creep", "Leap" cycle over three years when first transplanted. They'd be in the "Sleep" cycle this year. As for recommendations, remove the cardboard ASAP, as it kills all life in the soil, which definitely doesn't help your plants. See here for more information, if you're interested: https://gardenprofessors.com/the-cardboard-controversy/ - make sure to read the comments, as the author answers every single one of the points posed in them.